# I'm getting an error saying rm: cannot remove '.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

Tags: git, process, repository

First I get this error when I try to make any changes in git:

```
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

So I run `rm .git/index.lock`, and I get another error:

```
rm: cannot remove '.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is this on your lccal machine or a server? Have you tried deleting it manually?

Comment: Enter in this path where you become the first error `ls -la`. Do you see there a `.git` folder?

Comment: Can you add the OS you are using ? does this happen on a shared filesystem, or in a directory shared with a tool like iCloud or Dropbox client ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there were two files called COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp and index.lock that needed to be removed.  There was also some .vs file that apparently had been created by Visual Studio.